# How do I disable the window border in theme.lua/rc.lua (AwesomeWM)

Tags: lua, border, awesome-wm

I am trying to edit my `.config/awesome/theme.lua` and `.config/theme/rc.lua` files for AwesomeWM. I have the following lines in the `theme.lua` file:

```lua
theme.border_width = dpi(5)
theme.border_normal = "#14ff1b"
theme.border_focus = "#00158f"
```

Which works perfectly well - limey-green border on inactive window(s) and blue border on the active window. The issue is that I also am running polybar (after removing the `rc.lua` lines for the default bar) and am launching it like this in the `rc.lua` (it is out-of-place when I launch it from the `.xinitrc` after an AwesomeWM reload):

```lua
awful.spawn.with_shell("killall -q polybar") -- necesarry for a reload
awful.spawn.with_shell("polybar mybar") -- mybar is the name of the bar in `.config/polybar/config`
```

This permanently gives me an obnoxious green border around polybar, and my issue is that I want to remove that. I tried putting this in `rc.lua` before the above lines:

```lua
ruled.client.append_rule {
    rule = { class = "polybar" },
    properties = { client.border_width = 0 }
}
```

but this doesn't work. I looked around on Reddit and the AwesomeWM documentation, but this is the best that I could come up with, and it doesn't work. Does anyone know how I can do this, if I can even do this (remove the obnoxious 5dp border from Polybar, while keeping it on basically everything else).

Also, I tried changing it to `client.border_width = xresources.apply_dpi(0)`, because the default `theme.lua` file sets `dpi()`  as `xresources.apply_dpi()` and sets the border width to `dpi(2)` (which I changed to 5), but that didn't work either.

Update 1: I posted this on reddit, and after responses and more documentation reading I wrote this, which still doesn't work:

```lua
{ rule = { class = "Polybar" },
    properties = { border_width = 0 } }
```

I tried replacing "class" with "instance" and "name" (not rly sure hat the difference is), and I tried using both capitalized "Polybar" and lowercase "polybar", but those didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured this out. I asked on a reddit post, and I got two pieces of useful information from that:

- Since I don't use nightly, I cannot use ruled.*, and rather must use awful.rules.*
- "Polybar" may work while "polybar" may not.

So for the solution:

At one point in the `rc.lua`, you get the following:

```lua
awful.rules.rules = {
    { rule = { },
      properties = { border_width = beautiful.border_width,
                     border_color = beautiful.border_normal,
                     focus = awful.client.focus.filter,
                     raise = true,
                     keys = clientkeys,
                     buttons = clientbuttons,
                     screen = awful.screen.preferred,
                     placement = awful.placement.no_overlap+awful.placement.no_offscreen
      }
    }
    ...
```

So, that sets a bunch of stuff for all apps. I then commented out this part of this line:

```lua
      properties = { -- border_width = beautiful.border_width,
```

This then removed the border width and therefore the border. I then below that added a separate part that adds the border width to everything except polybar:

```lua
    { rule = { },
      except_any = { class = { "Polybar" } },
      properties = { border_width = beautiful.border_width }
    },
```

In case I want to remove the border from anything else in the future, I can do it like this:

```lua
except_any = { class = { "Polybar", "OtherApp1", "OtherApp2", "OtherApp3" } },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your rc.lua, it works for me

```
ruled.client.connect_signal("request::rules", function()
    ...
    ...
    ruled.client.append_rule {
        id = "Polybar",
        rule_any = {
            class = {"Ploybar"}
        },
        properties = {
            border_width = 0,
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```